# How to get out of an "if" while I'm reading a file?

Tags: c

My problem is that I enter in an "if" and the code doesn't continue reading the file!
I need to continue reading the file and comparing proxcasa and saux!
I think `fseek()` will solve that problem, but where and how should I use it in my code?

```
void ler_tabuleiro(lista_tabuleiro *t,FILE *entrada)
{
    TipoTabuleiro tabu;
    char proxcasa[100], regracasa[100], saux[20];
    strcpy(saux,"0");
    strcpy(proxcasa,"0");

    while(!feof(entrada))
    {
        fscanf(entrada," %s ",tabu.casa ); // nessa primeira leitura vamos ver se é tabuleiro

        if(strcmp(tabu.casa,"TABULEIRO")==0)
        {
            fscanf(entrada,"%s",tabu.casa);
        }
        else if( (strcmp(tabu.casa, "JOGADAS") == 0) || (strcmp(tabu.casa, "FIM") == 0) )
        {
            break;
        }

        if(strcmp(proxcasa,saux)==0) // o problema tá aqui !!! como proxcasa vai ser 0 ?
        {
            printf("entrou");
            fscanf(entrada, "%s %s %d",proxcasa,regracasa, &tabu.energia);
            printf("%s %s %s %d ",tabu.casa, proxcasa,regracasa,tabu.energia);
            inserirprimeiro(tabu,t,regracasa);
            strcpy(saux,tabu.casa);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `feof()` like that. Do test that the `fscanf()` worked correctly each time you call it. For the main loop, use `while (fscanf(entrada, " %s ", tabu.casa) == 1) { ... }`, and inside the loop, use `if (fscanf(...) != correct_number_of_values) { ...process error... }`.  Always test input operations to ensure they succeed.

Answer (score 3):

You should be clearer about your problem, but I suspect it is the `break` in the second `if` — this will break out of the file reading loop.

I've no idea how/why you think `fseek()` is appropriate.